# initialize an int[][] with new()

Tags: c++

I am a c++ newbie. While learning I came across this.

if I have a pointer like this

`int (*a)[2][3]`

cdecl.org describe this as `declare a as pointer to array 2 of array 3 of int:`

When I try

`int x[2][3];`

`a = &x;`

this works.

My question is how I can initialize `a` when using with new() say something like

`a = new int [] [];`

I tried some combinations but doesn't get it quite right.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably not the answer you're looking for, but what you
need is a new expression whose return type is `(*)[2][3]`  This
is fairly simple to do; that's the return type of `new int
[n][2][3]`, for example.  Do this, and `a` will point to the
first element of an array of [2] of array of [3] int.  A three
dimensional array, in sum.

The problem is that `new` doesn't return a pointer to the top
level array type; it returns a pointer to the first element of
the array.  So if you do `new int[2][3]`, the expression
*allocates* an array of 2 array of 3 int, but it returns
a pointer to an array of 3 int (`int (*a)[3]`), because in C++,
arrays are broken (for reasons of C compatibility).  And there's
no way of forcing it to do otherwise.  So if you want it to
return a pointer to a two dimensional array, you have to
allocate a three dimensional array.  (The first dimension can be
1, so `new [1][2][3]` would do the trick, and effectively only
allocate a single `[2][3]`.)

A better solution might be to wrap the array in a `struct`:

```
struct Array
{
    int data[2][3];
};
```

You can then use `new Array`, and everything works as expected.
Except that the syntax needed to access the array will be
different.

Comment: You may overload the `[]` operator and similar operators needed to manipulate an array and then even keep the syntax. I am not sure this is what the OP wants to achieve but at least it solves the problem for single memory allocation. +1 from me

Comment: @James Kanze : This helps much. Thanks. Selecting as the answer :)

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Good point.  You could even overload a conversion operator, to get the automatic conversion of array to pointer.  (In other words, emulate the way standard arrays are broken.)

Answer (score 5):

You will have to do it in two steps - first allocate an array of pointers to pointers(dynamically allocated arrays) and then, allocate each of them in turn. Overall I believe a better option is simply to use `std::vector` - that is the preferred `C++` way of doing this kind of things.

Still here is an example on how to achieve what you want:

```
int a**;
a = new int*[2];
for (int i =0; i< 2;++i){
  a[i] = new int[3]
}

... use them ...
// Don't forget to free the memory!
for (int i = 0; i< 2; ++i) {
  delete [] a[i];
}

delete [] a;
```

EDIT: and as requested by Default - the vector version:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > a(2, std::vector<int>(3,0));

// Use a and C++ will take care to free the memory.
```

Comment: what would it look like if you used `vector` instead?

Comment: So I assume there cant be a single statement like `a = new int [] [];`

Comment: This is totally incorrect.  `int [2][3]` is a single block of memory.

Comment: @JamesKanze true. Here the memory will not be sequential for different rows. Actually is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @Ivaylo. Thanks. I wonder what is the context where I have to use stuff like `int (*a)[2][3]`. :)

Comment: @JamesKanze : IMHO `a` is a ptr to a 2D array of dimensions 2 and 3. So a single block of memory might be OK here.

Comment: @NeonGlow in fact what James said here is that the solution I provide **will not** allocate a single block of memory but rather will allocate a block of memory for each row.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev : Ok. Got it. Sorry for messing it up.